# Network printing -- setting up and printing over network using Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, networking, printing, network-printer

I've connected a USB printer to a Mac OS X (10.4) machine -- this computer is connected to a network with a registered IP address -- and enabled sharing through the System Preferences setting (under "Shared" and "Print & Fax". Is this printer shared through the Bonjour or CUPS protocol (does it matter that I know)? How do I sent a print job to this computer (also from a 10.4 OS X machine on the same network)? It does not show up in the list of printers in the Default Network when I go to "add printer"; do I need to do anything else (on either machine)? Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CUPS isn't relevant, it's more of a doc-to-printer-instructions server. Bonjour just informs everyone of whats available. I havn't shared from a Mac, but sharing does seem to be very easy. What happens when you try to put the ip or name of the computer in the ip section? To check it's actually being shared use Bonjour Browser (or many many options on iphone).

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying info -- the Mac I'm trying to print from seems to accept the IP address as a "printer", but nothing happens when I try to print...